# Merge 2 tables in MySQL based on one column data

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have 2 MySQL tables that I want to merge as one.

Table Reservation

```
reservationidURL     checkin       checkout
      1.com         2017-01-01     2017-01-03
      2.com         2017-01-10     2017-01-20
      3.com         2017-02-05     2017-02-08
```

Table Room

```
reservationidURL    roomnumber
     1.com              1
     2.com             101
     3.com              7
```

How can I merge these 2 tables to get this table:

```
reservationidURL    checkin       checkout           roomnumber
     1.com         2017-01-01    2017-01-03              1
     2.com         2017-01-10    2017-01-20             101
     3.com         2017-02-05    2017-02-08              7
```

That meant that I want to keep the first table as is and just merge the second one to it based on the data of reservationidURL column.

Note: some columns in both tables have the same title, is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

Joins help retrieving data from two or more database tables. 
The tables are mutually related using primary and foreign keys.
 Those columns in both tables which has the same title will act as primary and foreign key. Read more about them [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html). A fiddle for the same [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb261c/1).

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.roomnumber 
FROM Reservation t1 
INNER JOIN Room t2 ON t1.reservationidURL = t2.reservationidURL
```

Comment: Shall I replace t1 and t2 here with table names?

Comment: t1 and t2 are used to write your tables only. It's short so that you don't have to write full names.

Answer (score 0):

First you add a new column to the table, then you do something like this:

```
UPDATE Reservation
INNER JOIN Room
    USING(reservationidURL)
SET Reservation.roomnumber = Room.roomnumber;
```